# Cookie set by Javascript not detected by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, subdomain

I've set a cookie in javascript, but my PHP file won't detect it. `print_r($_COOKIE)` results in `Array ( )`.

My set-up is mildly complex. I've got all the heavy lifting done by my site (`site.com`) and the end-result (HTML & Javascript) mirrored by the client site (`client.com`). So here's what happens:

1. `Client.com` sets a cookie with the domain `.site.com` and path `/` (using javascript).
2. `Client.com` does an AJAX request to `client.com/ajax.php` which is a mirror from `app.site.com/ajax.php`

The cookie is actually set. Here's what Chrome reports:

```
 Domain:    .site.com
 Path:  /
```

Since PHP is executed on app.site.com I'd expect my script to recognise the cookie set for .site.com, but it doesn't.

I've tried some combinations but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. It's important that javascript sets the cookie and PHP reads the cookie. Is this possible at all (since it's pseudo cross-domain)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't set a cookie to site.com from client.com for security reasons.

Comment: Seems weird that Chrome does actually set the cookie though. I'll probably have to resort to a serverside solution.